# Connecting 2 ADSL2 Modem Router in one splitter

Tags: router, modem, adsl-router, splitter, adsl2+

I am having a new ADSL2+ Modem Router. I brought it few days back when my old one got complaint. It's working well but it doesn't have good connectivity in specific places.

Today I received my old Modem Router replaced from service centre but not I have one not using..

This is my doubt. Can I split the main telephone line using splitter and connect both of them to two different Modem Routers (as shown in image below)?. If not possible I will have to sell one.

Comment: Excuse me... Where's the image? I'm almost running out of popcorn.

Comment: The simple answer would be: No. Certainly in the UK you can only have one ADSL Internet over one telephone line/number. If you are having problems with connectivity in a different area of your building then I would recommend purchasing a wifi repeater or, if your second router can be configured in this way, configuring it to act as a wifi bridge so that you connect it to your new modem/router with a long Ethernet cable and place it in the dead area of your building.

Comment: @BigChris: Certainly nothing to do with the UK. ADSL is a point-to-point link over a POTS line. The signalling simply does not permit splitters. A bridge/repeater would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, splitters are designed for 1 Modem and 1 Telephone connection. Telephones use a lower frequency than ADSL.

I would strongly recommend not using the port meant for telephones.